# Elastic search 2.0 Nest 2.0 datetime month search

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, search, nest

I have a requirement to get given month data from the datestart field.

```
public DateTime? datestart { get; set; }
```

I tried following code. But it did not work. Return no result.

```
string givenMonth = "5"; //May
            thisMonthQuery = Query<ProjectModel>.Match(
                q => q.Field(f => f.datestart.Value.Month.ToString()).Query(givenMonth));
```

Comment: You are trying to filter date which fall in a given month?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. I think now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Match query to search month in a date field. Date field is not split into different tokens like a text field so you cannot search on month.

You need to use a script query for this

```
.Script(sn => sn
    .Inline("doc['datestart'].value.monthOfYear==param1")
    .Params(p => p.Add("param1", 5))
)
```

You can also create a sub field of type text and use match query, but then your input can also match date part!.